# Geo location not getting loaded in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: angular, google-maps, internet-explorer-11

I am working on angular 6 and I am trying to get lat/long of the current location using Geo location of Google maps in Internet Explorer 11. But unable to get the coordinates. Please find my code below,

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
this.location = position.coords;
this.lat = +this.location["latitude"].toFixed(6);
this.lng = +this.location["longitude"].toFixed(6);
});
}
```

Comment: Do you meet any error? Try to use F12 developer tools to check whether it contains some error? Besides, since you are using Angular 6 with IE 11, please check the polyfills.ts file, and make sure you have uncomment the related import for the IE browser. Here is an article about using [google maps Geolocation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation), you could refer to it.

Comment: I am not getting any error. I checked my polyfills.ts file, installed all required packages and uncommented the import sections.